# Proving a relation is transative with regards to a relation represented by a linear equation inequality.

Tags: real-analysis

Say you have some arbitrary linear function expressed as an inequality.

How would you go about testing whether the function is transitive or not with regards to an equivalence relation.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Maybe give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Say the function is y>=x, given x, y, z are in the set of reals.

Comment: I suppose it would depend on the specific equivalence relation.

Comment: The function is the equivalence relation.

Comment: $y\ge x$ is a relation, not a function. A function is not an equivalence relation. I know what it means to test whether a relation is transitive, but not what it means to test whether a relation is transitive with regards to an equivalence relation. Please try to use mathematical terminology with due respect to what the words actually mean.